# How to disable window.alert for specific function and re-enable it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trigger change event for dropdown using jquery,

```
var year = jQuery("#cq-year option:eq(2)").val();
jQuery("#cq-year").val(year).trigger('change');
```

but its showing error in alert **"missing required parameter to GetModels."**
 I had disable alert on `jQuery(window).load`but i just want to disable alert for these specific alert.

```
window.alert = function() { };
```

so how can i re-enable this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the `window.alert` function in a temporary variable and reassign it when you're finished.

```js
var temp = window.alert;
window.alert = function() { };
alert('this is not shown');
window.alert = temp;
alert('this is shown');
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot its working now, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
// Flag for alert
var canAlert = false;

// Backup the alert method
var alertBackup = window.alert

// Over ride alert method
window.alert = function(msg){
    // Check if flag is enabled before alerting
    if(canAlert){
        alertBackup(msg)
    }
}
```

Make `canAlert = true` when ever you want the alert to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility function `callNoAlert` for that:

```js
function callNoAlert (fn) {
  var a = alert
  window.alert = Function.prototype
  fn()
  window.alert = a
}

callNoAlert(function () {
  alert("ANNOYING ALERT!") // does not run!
  console.log("alert() didn't run!")
})

callNoAlert(function () {
  var year = jQuery("#cq-year option:eq(2)").val();
  jQuery("#cq-year").val(year).trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```